# Unable to establish secure connection with the server , when using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and I have added the following provider to my asp.net `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Version=4.0.0.0" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="ad-domainA.intra\it360ad.user" connectionPassword="$$$$$3" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
```

&

```
<add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="LDAP://10.211.12.30.ad-domainA.intra/CN=Users,DC=ad-domainA,DC=intra" />
```

but when the users try to access the application and they enter username and password , this will raise the following exception :

> Unable to establish secure connection with the server

So what might be the problem? and also is it right to include my server IP address inside the connection string as I am doing ?

**EDIT**

I changed my setting to be:

```
 <system.web>
        <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <add name="TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,Version=4.0.0.0" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="it360ad.user" connectionPassword="$$$$$" />

          </providers>
        </membership>
```

&

```
  <add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" 
       connectionString="LDAP://ad-domainA.intra/OU=TM,DC=ad-doaminA,DC=intra" />
```

but currently the following check

```
if(domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

inside the `Account` controller action method will return

> The user name or password provided is incorrect

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   MembershipProvider domainProvider;

   domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];

   // Validate the user with the membership system.
   if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
   {
       //code goes here
   }
   else
   {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
       return View(model);
   }
```

Can you advice why the validation will always fail ?

Thanks

Comment: That server you define after the `LDAP://` is odd - **either** you should use an IP address like `10.211.12.30`, **OR** you should use a symbolic name like `ad-domainA.intra` - but you cannot mix both.....

Comment: but "ad-domianA.intra" is the domain name, while the IP is the server where the AD is installed. so why i can not mib both ?

Comment: The **IP** already clearly and uniquely identifies the **single machine** that you want to connect to. No need to add a domain name to an IP address.....

Comment: thanks a lot for you help, currently the exception is gone , but the authentication check will always fail. can you check my edit ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `connectionString="LDAP://10.211.12.30:389 />`. I had the same problem and I found that I had to remove anything else after `:389`in the connection string.

I dont know why that is but it worked for me..... Hope this helps

Comment: Very strange solution but it worked. My app all of a sudden stopped working but once I removed the port # then it started working again.